# Search in Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscribe

I have this object :

```
combineLatest( 
this.toppings.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings.value)),
this.toppings2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.toppings2.value)))
.subscribe(val => console.log(val))


(2) [Array(9), Array(2)]
0:(9) ["Douleur", "Psychologie", "Nutrition", "Social", "Rééducation physique", "Hygiène de vie", "Sexualité et fertilité", "Soins palliatifs", "Oncogériatrie"]

1:(2) ["CHU Nantes", "CH Le Mans"]

length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

How i can do a condition like ? 
`if ("CHU Nantes" is in the object val)` or 
`if ("Douleur" or "Psychologie" is in the object val)`, so...

I try this within results :

```
if (val.includes("CHU Nantes")) { 
 CHUNantes.addTo(myfrugalmap);
} else { 
  CHUNantes.remove();
};
console.log(val);
```

Comment: Please explain properly what you want to achieve ?? that doesn't looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the array to search all values. For example: `val.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []).includes("CHU Nantes");`

For modern browser you can use Array.prototype.flat also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility

Comment: merci beaucoup!